# When Vue Component mounted hook called, have all the DOMs inside already been rendered?

Tags: vue.js

**UPDATE: I forget to remove v-if in that div level which prevents the underlying element from getting rendered**

---

Quick question, in Vue, if I have a component like:

```
<uploader></uploader>
```

inside its template:

```
<div><input type="file" ref="upldr" /></div>
```

I wonder why I can not access that input DOM like:

```
this.$refs.upldr
```

It gives me `undefined`

Does it mean that when the mounted hook gets called, all the DOM elements inside the template have not been rendered?

Thanks,

Comment: All of the DOM elements inside a component's template have been rendered at the point when `mounted` is called. Here's a simple fiddle using the info you've provided: https://jsfiddle.net/qp0g1m76/

Comment: My first thought is that you have the `<input/>` inside of a `v-if` that is evaluating to false. In that case, the `v-if` element and its contents would not be present in the DOM. If that's not the case, you'd need to share an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as there could be a lot of things causing the value to be `undefined`.

Comment: @thanksd Thanks, that is exactly what I did stupidly.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the official Vue documentation for its lifecycle.

According to this, once you reach the `mounted` hook the DOM will be fully rendered and done. It's the very last hook you can attach to that isn't an event or an exiting function.

So in short: Yes, once you reach `mounted` everything is ready and good to go, the rest is just related to updating or exiting Vue.

[image]